# Store bash string comparison in variable

Tags: bash

I want to store the result of a bash string comparison in a variable, with effect equivalent to:

```
if [[ $a == $b ]]; then
    res=1
else
    res=0
fi
```

I was hoping to be able to write something terser, like:

```
res2=$('$a'=='$b') #Not valid bash
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want, without deferring to an if construct?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I would suggest either:

```
res=0; [ "$a" == "$b" ] && res=1
```

or

```
res=1; [ "$a" == "$b" ] || res=0
```

Not quite as simple as you were hoping for, but does avoid the `if ... else ... fi`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think in this form I would prefer to go with `[ "$a" == "$b" ] && res=1 || res=0` as it has the more familiar c-style ternary structure.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use the `$?` variable which contains the return value from the previous command:

```
res="$( [[ $a == $b ]]; echo $? )"
```

Although that would inverse the numbers you gave.  The end result would be the same as:

```
if [[ $a == $b ]]; then
  res=0
else
  res=1
fi
```

That's because the shell interprets a return value of `0` as true and `1` as false.

Not saying I wholly advocate this solution either.  It's hackish and a bit unclear.  But it is terse and terse is what you asked for.

Answer (score 2):

```bash
res2=$(expr "$a" == "$b")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option.

```
$> test "foo" = "bar"; res=$?
$> echo $res
1
$> test "foo" = "foo"; res=$?
$> echo $res
0
```